# How to insert a linked image into the body of a new email?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I want to insert a linked image into the body of a new email using Outlook 2010/13 VBA.

I want to insert it either where the cursor is or after the last character of the email body.

The code below inserts the image in a new line after the end of the body.

Note that I can insert this image at any place in the body of the email when I use the "Insert and Link Picture" Outlook feature using its GUI.

```
Sub test_add_image()
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set NewMail = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
    NewMail.HTMLBody = NewMail.HTMLBody & "<img   src=http://www.example.com/image.html>"
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot concatenate 2 HTML strings and end up with a valid html. E.g. <html><body>test</body></html> & <img src="blah"/> is not a valid html

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the message body and find the place where you want the image to be inserted. So, at least you need to get a well-formed HTML markup. The `img` tag should be inside the `body` element.

Comment: Eugene, thank you for your reply. The image can be inserted at any place as it is done when inserting the image manually. Therefore the code should know where the courser is and insert the image there. If this cannot be done, it should be inserted at the end of the last character in the body. Can you modify my code and show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a local file as an image at the current cursor position, use  `Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture` - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff822636.aspx